# Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'system.dbnull'

Tags: c#, ado.net

I'm retrieving data from a DB. Therefore I'm using the following code:

```
compname.Text = mRS.Fields["CompName"].Value == DBNull.Value
              ? ""
              : mRS.Fields["CompName"].Value.ToString();
```

At run time I'm getting the following error:

> Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'System.DBNull'

What causes the error?

Comment: You are trying to check whether string == DBNull(object)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because `mRS.Fields["CompName"].Value` is the value of that field and is of type string and `DBNull.Value` is of type DBNull.

You should compare `DBNull.Value` to the field itself (and not its value), like this:

```
compname.Text = DBNull.Value.Equals(mRS.Fields["CompName"]) ? "" : mRS.Fields["CompName"].Value;
```

Comment: when i am using above code it is giving "Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Field' and 'DBNull'"

Comment: another error "Can not implicitly convert type 'bool to 'string'"'

Comment: I edited my answer, please confirm that you tried with exactly how it is in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
compname.Text = mRS.Fields["CompName"].Value == DBNull.Value ? "" : mRS.Fields["CompName"].Value.ToString();
```

to

```
compname.Text = mRS.Fields["CompName"] == DBNull.Value ? "" : mRS.Fields["CompName"].Value;
```

Comment: when i am using above code it is giving "Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Field' and 'DBNull'"